# Is this a correct alternative to a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

The `for` loop increments the variable and continues to run the set of statements in it untill the condition is false.
Is this a correct alternative to the `for` loop?

```
abc : i++;
if(i<=10)
{    
    goto abc;
}
```

My question is,

Is this a correct alternative? If not, how does the `for` loop actually work?

Comment: No. Your version will never stop, since the `goto` is unconditional.

Comment: Goto is often [considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

Comment: `how does the 'for' loop actually work` => a while loop with a declaration above it and an increment/decrement at the bottom

Comment: Can I suggest you do some research before posting?  "c++ for loop example" gets plenty of results.

Comment: @KevinL I don't think a for loop is actually defined in terms of a while; although it certainly could be.

Comment: @Carcigenicate See 6.5.3 of the C++14 spec, it literally says `for(init; condition; iter) { body }` is equivalent to `{init; while(condition) { body; iter; }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code can be an alternative to a `for` loop. You just need to take care of all parts like initialization, condition, iteration count, etc.

```
int i=0;
abc: i++;
if(i<10){
  printf("i is %d\n", i);
  goto abc;
```

}

When a `for` loop is compiled, the assembler uses goto-like statements to generate assembly code for a loop(for, while). It is not, however, advisable to use `goto` as readability of code will be low and it can also be harmful in some cases. So, we should not use it.

Answer (score 9):

A `for` loop can be lowered from

```
for(int x = 10; x > 0; x--) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

to

```
{
    int x = 10;
    loop: // for doesn't introduce a label
    if(x > 0) {
        {
            cout << x << endl;
        }
        x--;
        goto loop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uah... `goto` is still considered harmfull. And I don't expect that to change.

You can replace a for loop with a while loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 42; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

Is equivalent to

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 42) {
        /* ... */
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: OP was asking about how for was implemented or equivalent to. This did not even try to answer it.